# constexpr as part of the mutable member

Tags: c++, c++14

This is the definition of the [assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%3D) operator for the std::basic_string_view

`constexpr basic_string_view& operator=(const basic_string_view& view) noexcept = default;`

Is anybody able to explain to me what is the purpose to have constexpr for an **assignment operator**?

Even more general question what is the reason to make mutable member constexpr? Using VS2015 compiler I had a warning such as

> in C++14 'constexpr' will not imply 'const'; consider explicitly specifying 'const'

Shouldn't it be an error instead?

Comment: If the variable on the RHS is constexpr, the assignment can be performed at compile-time.  Making a mutable member constexpr allows changing its contents at compile-time (this wasn't possible before when constexpr implied const).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a local variable in a constexpr context and modify it in C++14.

However if the assignment operator isn't constexpr, you cannot use it.

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<T, N> sort( std::array<T, N> in ) {
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i) {
    for (std::size_t j = i+1; j < in.size(); ++j) {
      if (in[i] > in[j]) {
        auto tmp = in[j];
        in[j] = in[i];
        in[i] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
  return in;
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f55a36fd3f6ffb74).

Comment: Could you please provide a compilable example which shows what you said.

Comment: @AntonDyachenko Sure, toy selection sort added.

Comment: Basically in c++14 constexpr means pretty much the same thing as pure in D language.